# Sending data from Python to R to perform statistical test using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I want to use the [Fisher's exact test functionality](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/fisher.test.html) (specifically, the MC simulation functionality) of R with an interface to Python. I'm trying to do that using [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/introduction.html), but it's more difficult than I thought.

I can get an interface to the Fisher's test method using the following code:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
fisher = robjects.r['fisher.test']
```

However, how do I pass a `2xN` matrix to the function and retrieve the p-value?

Answer (score 2):

Consider importing R's stats package and run the Fisher Test as a Python function. Do note, the `result` object is `<class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.ListVector'>` and hence must be converted to a Python dictionary as shown below.

```
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri import numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import numpy as np

cont = np.reshape(np.arange(0,4), (2,2))

statspackage = importr('stats',  robject_translations={'format_perc': '_format_perc'})    
result = statspackage.fisher_test(numpy2ri(cont), simulate_p_value = True, B = 100)

# DEPRECATED CONVERSION
import pandas.rpy.common as com
pyresultdict = com.convert_robj(result)

for k, v in  pyresultdict.items():
    print(k, v)

# data.name ['structure(c(0L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Dim = c(2L, 2L))']
# p.value [1.0]
# estimate odds ratio    0.0
# dtype: float64
# null.value odds ratio    1.0
# dtype: float64
# conf.int [0.0, 77.90626902008512]
# alternative ['two.sided']
# method ["Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data"]
```

---

Another note, you may receive a warning about the deprecation of `com.convert_to_r_dataframe` and `com.convert_robj(rdf)` which should be replaced with `pandas2ri.pandas2ri()` and `pandas2ri` as suggested [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html). However, the conversion on my end does not work for the *ListVector* object. Ideally, above conversion would be replaced with below:

```
# CURRENT CONVERSION
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
pyresultdict = pandas2ri.ri2py(result)

for k, v in  pyresultdict.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like a less hacky approach. Is there any direct benefit of this approach?

Comment: You work in the Python object model and avoid passing R script lines for each task.

Comment: @Parfait I have the import of the R package working with simply `statspackage = importr('stats')` (using R-3.3.0-beta)

Comment: There was a [bug in earlier version](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/274/name-conversion-rule-when-there-is-a-dot) with naming conflict of `format_perc` so ignore if works for you. It might help future readers.

Comment: Curious @lgautier if you are same [BitBucket user](https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/), did the bottom  conversion work in converting the R `vectors.ListVector` object to Python dictionary? I posted an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13018) but was immediately closed as pandas does not maintain rpy2.

Comment: @Parfait - same person. If rpy2's issue tracker is accurate the bug was fixed with rpy2-2.6.0 (current release is 2.7.8, 2.8.0 scheduled for release in about 3 weeks). R's lists (`ListVector` objects with rpy2) are not going to  convert to pandas data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri import numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import numpy as np

cont = np.reshape(np.arange(0,4), (2,2))
print cont

r_cont = numpy2ri(cont)
r.assign("cont", r_cont)
r("res <- fisher.test(cont, simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 100)")
r_result = r("res")
p_value = r_result[0][0]
print r_result
print p_value
```